# PHP - Method with parameters as a parameter to other method

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am trying to get result from this method (1st param is the service name, 2nd is method with its own parameters):

```
$userFacade->getSet('users', 'findBy([], [\'id\' => \'DESC\'])')
```

This is the getSet method:

```
public function getSet($service, $function)
{
    return new Set($this->$service->getRepository()->$function);
}
```

All I want to achieve is to make writing of calls of the repository's functions easier. I haven't found anything useful yet because I don't know the proper term to search for (if there is one). I just wonder whether it's possible (how?) or not (ok...).

Now I get an error:

```
Cannot read an undeclared property EntityRepository::$findBy([], ['id' => 'DESC'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
$userFacade->getSet('users', 'findBy', [], ['id' => 'DESC']);
```

and

```
public function getSet($service, $function, ...$args) {
    return new Set($this->$service->getRepository()->$function($args));
}
```

using new PHP 5.6 variadics

Comment: Thank you for reply. I cannot use 5.6 right now but your answer brought me to the right path. I have changed my code to this: `return call_user_func_array($this->$service->getRepository()->$function, $args);`